# How to use camera as texture image in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

In three.js, I am trying to create a texture whose image is the current scene as viewed from a Camera.  Using a CubeCamera to create a similar effect is well-documented; and with CubeCamera I have created an example of a scene to illustrate my goal at:

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Camera-Texture-Almost.html

However, I would like to use a regular Camera (rather than a CubeCamera) as the texture.  How could I do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the Three.js render-to-texture example? http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_rtt.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ideally this would work.

Init:

```
renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( 512, 512, { format: THREE.RGBFormat } );

var planelikeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 400, 200, 200 );
var plane = new THREE.Mesh( planelikeGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: renderTarget } ) );
plane.position.set(0,100,-500);
scene.add(plane);
```

Render:

```
renderer.render( scene, topCamera, renderTarget, true );
renderer.render( scene, topCamera );
```

And it almost does, but we have some unfinished business with y-flipped textures that ruins the party here.

So the best solution at the moment is to use the intermediry quad for flipping the texture (also saves a render):

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_rtt.html

Answer (score 4):

Based on mrdoob's example and suggestions, I have created a working example with very detailed comments, available at:

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Camera-Texture.html

part of my series of tutorial-style Three.js series of examples at

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/

Comment: It was nicer when the `TrackballControls` were in place, you could appreciate the recursion a bit more :)

Comment: Something bad is happening in Safari 5.1.7 and Firefox 13.0.1 -- on my machine, at least. ( Works OK in Chrome 20.0.1132.47 ) Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4, AMD Radeon HD 6750M 512 MB
Screenshot: http://imgur.com/nfPEi

Comment: That is quite odd... I have no idea why that might be happening... do any of my other Three.js tutorials at http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/ produce similar effects?

Comment: Only http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Reflection.html produces the same effect (Safari and FF). Chrome works.

Comment: Ack! The culprit: the CSS body { background-color: #ccccff; } is masking the entire screen. Perhaps it is better to set the renderer's clearColor property instead.